# improve vista running speed

Tags: windows-vista, performance, speed

I know that the best method of improving the performanmces of a system with Windows Vista is to format the c: partition and install all the needed software from scrach.

Do you know any good software which clean the system registry, it show me which programs haven't been used from some time, and other features like that?

When i was a litle kid, i was using the Norton Utilities and later the System Mechanics. On my computers i preffer to reinstal the windows from scarch. Now i have to improve the working speed of a freind computer. What advices do you have for me?

That vista was intalled 1 year ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- use **[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)** to weed out the Startup routine.
- visit **[Blackviper.com](http://www.blackviper.com/Articles/OS/OSguides.htm#Windows_Vista)** and read the Vista tweaking guides.
- [disable drive indexing](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/09/17/disable-and-turn-off-windows-vista-search-indexer-and-indexing-service/) if you don't need context search (or use **[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)** and do away with Windows Desktop Search altogether).
- run [**Ccleaner**](http://www.ccleaner.com/download) to delete temporary files on a regular basis (get the Slim build w/o browser bar).
- defragment the system drive.
- get the **[Windows Installer CleanUp Utility](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Secure-cleaning/Windows-Installer-CleanUp-Utility.shtml)** to remove old Windows Installers.
- use **[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)** to uninstall software, remove programs and solve uninstall problems.
- scan the system with **[MBAM](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php)** for possible malware infections.

the bendefits of so called 'registry cleaners' are debatable, read Mark Russinovich's take on the issue:

**[Registry Junk: A Windows Fact of Life](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2005/10/02/registry-junk-a-windows-fact-of-life.aspx)**

however, i do use **[RegSeeker](http://www.hoverdesk.net/freeware.htm)**, not for the 'clean-up' function but because of the speed and certain features that MS RegEdit is lacking.

Comment: Be careful: if you disable drive indexing on the wrong directories the menu search might stop working.

Comment: autoruns:do you talk about run->autorun?

Comment: no, i'm talking about the program i have linked to. a startup manager for Windows. sorry, i edited the link.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using **TuneUp Utilities** for a long time now, and it gives pretty good results.

> The app provides users with a
>   powerful, well-designed utility that
>   accesses the entire Windows
>   maintenance tool set and more in a
>   fast, organized, and easy-to-use
>   series of connected modules.

You can check it out here : http://download.cnet.com/TuneUp-Utilities-2010/3000-18512_4-10206416.html

Answer (score 0):

Set the theme for classic windows.  It will turn off all of the graphics enhancements and leave you with a vanilla gui.  This will help a lot with memory usage if that is a problem area for you.